# Accessing HTML source on event DownloadComplete?

Tags: c++, browser, webbrowser-control, mshtml, ihtmldocument2

I am working on a ads/popup blocker BHO and I am trying to access the html of a website from the event "downloadcomplete", so I can filter all the ads and malicious uris.

My code looks something like this:

```
case DISPID_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE:
    {
        if(iBrowser) //IWebBrowser2*
        {
            HRESULT hr;
            IUnknown *pUnkBrowser = NULL;   

            hr = iBrowser->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void**)&pUnkBrowser);

            if( SUCCEEDED(hr) && pUnkBrowser!=NULL)
            {
                if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
                {
                    IDispatch* pHtmlDocDispatch = NULL;

                    IHTMLDocument2 * pHtmlDoc = NULL;

                    hr = iBrowser->get_Document (&pHtmlDocDispatch);

                    if (SUCCEEDED (hr) && (pHtmlDocDispatch != NULL))
                    {
                        hr = pHtmlDocDispatch->QueryInterface (IID_IHTMLDocument2,  (void**)&pHtmlDoc);

                        if (SUCCEEDED (hr) && (pHtmlDoc != NULL))
                        {
                            IHTMLElement *pBody = 0;

                            pHtmlDoc->get_body( &pBody );
                            // I want to get the html here and filter out the ads but pBody is always null

                            if(pHtmlDoc) pHtmlDoc->Release();

                        }

                        if(pHtmlDocDispatch) pHtmlDocDispatch->Release();
                    }
                }

                if(pUnkBrowser) pUnkBrowser->Release();
            }
        }
        return S_OK;
    }
    break;
```

**How could I access and modify the html from this event?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong event, you can "play" with the dom on the DocumentComplete, not the DownloadComplete.

Also I would advise you to use CComPtr, that way you don't need to call the release() on every interface.

Comment: But on the DocumentComplete event the ads and malicious js are already being loaded into the browser.

Comment: if you want to modify the DOM then the browser must have loaded the html.

Comment: but on DownloadComplete, doesn't the complete html already exists somewhere and is about to be processed by mshtml? Cant that be intercepted?

Comment: You have to wait for the HTML to be parsed before you can access it via DOM interfaces. The `DownloadComplete` event is fired when the raw data has finished being downloaded, but the browser has not processed it yet. Instead of using `IHTMLDocument2_get_body()`, try using `IPersistStream::Save()` instead. To load modified HTML back into the browser, use `IPersistStreamInit::Load()` (you will have to cancel the original request first).